I want to use tree struct in presale instructions. But it takes more memory than 16 bytes please suggest a way to access Tree Struct form white list
Whitelist :-
use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    merkletreers::{tree::MerkleTree, utils::hash_it},
    solana_program::{entrypoint::ProgramResult, msg, program_error::ProgramError},
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct WhitelistArgs {
    pub accounts: Vec<String>,
}

const ADMIN_ACCOUNT: &str = "Cv66dQwcSJDdXNVHybchYqp73d75Y8XWj6pKcjN3ffAy";

pub struct Tree {
    pub merkle_tree: MerkleTree,
}

pub(crate) static mut WHITELIST_TREE: Option<Tree> = None;

pub fn whitelist_account(args: WhitelistArgs, admin_account: String) -> ProgramResult {
    if admin_account != ADMIN_ACCOUNT {
        return Err(ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
    }

    let leaves: Vec<[u8; 32]> = args
        .accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|account_str| {
            let account_bytes = account_str.as_bytes();
            let mut buffer = [0u8; 32];
            hash_it(account_bytes, &mut buffer);
            buffer
        })
        .collect();

    let whitelist_tree = MerkleTree::new(leaves);

    let tree = Tree {
        merkle_tree: whitelist_tree,
    };

    msg!("Accounts have been added to the whitelist");
    msg!("{:?}", tree.merkle_tree.root);

    unsafe {
        WHITELIST_TREE = Some(tree);
    }

    Ok(())
}`enter code here`

Processor:- Where i want to pass my Tree struct in instruction
use solana_program::program_error::ProgramError;

use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    solana_program::{account_info::AccountInfo, entrypoint::ProgramResult, pubkey::Pubkey},
};

use crate::instructions::{
    self, 
    create::{create_token, CreateTokenArgs}, 
    mint::{mint_token, MintSplArgs}, 
    presale::{pre_sale, BuyerArgs, PreSaleArgs}, 
    transfer::{transfer_tokens, TransferTokensArgs}, 
    whitelist::{whitelist_account, WhitelistArgs}
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
enum MyInstruction {
    Create(CreateTokenArgs),
    MintSpl(MintSplArgs),
    TransferTokens(TransferTokensArgs),
    WhiteListAccount(WhitelistArgs, String),
    PreSale(),
}

pub(crate) static mut WHITELIST_TREE: Option<&instructions::Tree> = None;

// impl AsRef<instructions::Tree> for instructions::Tree {
//     fn as_ref(&self) -> &instructions::Tree {
//         self
//     }
// }

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    
    let instruction = MyInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)?;

    match instruction {
        MyInstruction::Create(args) => create_token(accounts, args),
        MyInstruction::MintSpl(args) => mint_token(accounts, args),
        MyInstruction::TransferTokens(args) => transfer_tokens(accounts, args),
        MyInstruction::WhiteListAccount(args, admin_account) => {
            match whitelist_account(args, admin_account) {
                Ok(_) => Ok(()), 
                Err(err) => Err(err), 
            }
        }
        MyInstruction::PreSale() => {
            let tree = unsafe { WHITELIST_TREE.unwrap() }; 
            pre_sale(accounts, tree )
        }   
    }
}
 


Does this answer your question? How can i pass 4 arguments in entrypoint of solana_program. This function takes 4 arguments but 3 arguments were supplied
